# How to hide, or at least customize colorbar in plotly scattergeo in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, colorbar

I want to create a scattergeo plot with markers for capitals. These markers are sized and colored regarding database values.

If I use the standard colors, everything goes well : the map is shown properly with good size, different colors, and no legend (I add the information country:value in a hover text on the markers).

However if I use a custom palette using colors feature into my scattergeo plot the colorbar is always displayed. Showlegend=F and Showscale=F doesn't help. Since I remove colors the colorbar disapeared.
Moreover, if I try to customize it (eg change the title or the format of the tickslabels) it doesn't work.

In other words no option I have tried on this colorbar works !

This is my data :

```
structure(list(ISO3 = c("ARG", "AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "BRA", "CAN", 
"CHE", "CHL", "CHN", "COK", "DEU", "DNK", "ESP", "FIN", "FJI", 
"FRA", "GBR", "HKG", "IDN", "IND", "ITA", "JPN", "KOR", "LUX", 
"MEX", "MYS", "NCL", "NLD", "NOR", "NZL", "PHL", "PRT", "RUS", 
"SGP", "SWE", "THA", "TON", "USA", "WSM"), Total = c(1073L, 8204L, 
818L, 1502L, 1871L, 7958L, 3524L, 2456L, 3345L, 456L, 5010L, 
569L, 2775L, 184L, 75L, 60382L, 4424L, 415L, 146L, 405L, 8369L, 
8176L, 1034L, 235L, 961L, 137L, 6522L, 667L, 309L, 7960L, 238L, 
316L, 486L, 404L, 480L, 200L, 41L, 85225L, 46L), Size = c(16, 
30, 14, 18, 19, 30, 24, 21, 23, 12, 26, 13, 22, 8, 5, 50, 25, 
11, 7, 11, 30, 30, 16, 9, 15, 7, 28, 13, 10, 30, 9, 10, 12, 11, 
12, 8, 3, 54, 4), Color = c(3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2), ISO2 = c("AR", "AU", "AT", "BE", "BR", 
"CA", "CH", "CL", "CN", "CK", "DE", "DK", "ES", "FI", "FJ", "FR", 
"GB", "HK", "ID", "IN", "IT", "JP", "KR", "LU", "MX", "MY", "NC", 
"NL", "NO", "NZ", "PH", "PT", "RU", "SG", "SE", "TH", "TO", "US", 
"WS"), LABELFR = c("Argentine", "Australie", "Autriche", "Belgique", 
"Brésil", "Canada", "Suisse", "Chili", "Chine", "Iles Cook", 
"Allemagne", "Danemark", "Espagne", "Finlande", "Fidji", "France", 
"Royaume-Uni", "Hong-kong, Chine", "Indonésie", "Inde", "Italie", 
"Japon", "Corée, République de", "Luxembourg", "Mexique", "Malaisie", 
"Nouvelle-Calédonie", "Pays-Bas", "Norvège", "Nouvelle-Zélande", 
"Philippines", "Portugal", "Russie, Fédération de", "Singapour", 
"Suède", "Thaïlande", "Tonga", "Etats-Unis", "Samoa"), LABELEN = c("Argentina", 
"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Canada", "Switzerland", 
"Chile", "China", "Cook Islands", "Germany", "Denmark", "Spain", 
"Finland", "Fiji", "France", "United Kingdom", "Hong Kong", "Indonesia", 
"India", "Italy", "Japan", "South Korea", "Luxembourg", "Mexico", 
"Malaysia", "New Caledonia", "Netherlands", "Norway", "New Zealand", 
"Philippines", "Portugal", "Russia", "Singapore", "Sweden", "Thailand", 
"Tonga", "United States", "Samoa"), CAPITAL = c("Buenos Aires", 
"Canberra", "Vienna", "Brussels", "Brasilia", "Ottawa", "Bern", 
"Santiago", "Beijing", "Avarua", "Berlin", "Copenhagen", "Madrid", 
"Helsinki", "Suva", "Paris", "London", "N/A", "Jakarta", "New Delhi", 
"Rome", "Tokyo", "Seoul", "Luxembourg", "Mexico City", "Kuala Lumpur", 
"Noumea", "Amsterdam", "Oslo", "Wellington", "Manila", "Lisbon", 
"Moscow", "Singapore", "Stockholm", "Bangkok", "Nuku'alofa", 
"Washington", "Apia"), LATITUDE = c("-34.583333333333336", "-35.266666666666666", 
"48.2", "50.833333333333336", "-15.783333333333333", "45.416666666666664", 
"46.916666666666664", "-33.45", "39.916666666666664", "-21.2", 
"52.516666666666666", "55.666666666666664", "40.4", "60.166666666666664", 
"-18.133333333333333", "48.86666666666667", "51.5", "0", "-6.166666666666667", 
"28.6", "41.9", "35.68333333333333", "37.55", "49.6", "19.433333333333334", 
"3.1666666666666665", "-22.266666666666666", "52.35", "59.916666666666664", 
"-41.3", "14.6", "38.71666666666667", "55.75", "1.2833333333333332", 
"59.333333333333336", "13.75", "-21.133333333333333", "38.883333", 
"-13.816666666666666"), LONGITUDE = c("-58.666667", "149.133333", 
"16.366667", "4.333333", "-47.916667", "-75.700000", "7.466667", 
"-70.666667", "116.383333", "-159.766667", "13.400000", "12.583333", 
"-3.683333", "24.933333", "178.416667", "2.333333", "-0.083333", 
"0.000000", "106.816667", "77.200000", "12.483333", "139.750000", 
"126.983333", "6.116667", "-99.133333", "101.700000", "166.450000", 
"4.916667", "10.750000", "174.783333", "120.966667", "-9.133333", 
"37.600000", "103.850000", "18.050000", "100.516667", "-175.200000", 
"-77.000000", "-171.766667"), CONTINENT = c("South America", 
"Australia", "Europe", "Europe", "South America", "Central America", 
"Europe", "South America", "Asia", "Australia", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Australia", "Europe", "Europe", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Central America", 
"Asia", "Australia", "Europe", "Europe", "Australia", "Asia", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Europe", "Asia", "Australia", "Central America", 
"Australia")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-39L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001ffb6417970>, sorted = "ISO3")
```

This is my code :

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scattergeo',
  showlegend=F,
  mode='markers',
  data=TOUR,
  y=~LATITUDE,
  x=~LONGITUDE,
  text=sprintf("%s : %s",TOUR$LABELFR,TOUR$Total),
  hovertemplate = "%{text}<extra></extra>",
  colors=c(ispfPalette[c(9,4,2)]),
  color=~Color,
  marker=list(
    showscale=F,
    size=~Size,
    reversescale=F
    )
  )
```

And this is the output I have :

[image]

Best solution would be to hide completely the colorbar, but I would also be curious how to customize it by changing the title and formatting the values (per example in case of % or if I want to change the decimal separator).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** on request:

You could modify the colorbar in the `colors` argument, for example like this:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scattergeo',
  showlegend=F,
  mode='markers',
  data=TOUR,
  y=~LATITUDE,
  x=~LONGITUDE,
  text=sprintf("%s : %s",TOUR$LABELFR,TOUR$Total),
  hovertemplate = "%{text}<extra></extra>",
  colors="YlOrRd",
 #colors = c("#1B98E0","black"),
  color=~Color,
  marker=list(
    showscale=F,
    size=~Size,
    reversescale=F
  ) 
)
fig
```

`colors="YlOrRd"`
[image]

`colors = c("#1B98E0","black")`
[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
Just add: `%>% hide_colorbar` at the end of your code:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scattergeo',
  showlegend=F,
  mode='markers',
  data=TOUR,
  y=~LATITUDE,
  x=~LONGITUDE,
  text=sprintf("%s : %s",TOUR$LABELFR,TOUR$Total),
  hovertemplate = "%{text}<extra></extra>",
  colors=c(ispfPalette[c(9,4,2)]),
  color=~Color,
  marker=list(
    showscale=F,
    size=~Size,
    reversescale=F
    )
  ) %>% hide_colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. A quick and easy answer ! Any tips on how to customise this colorbar instead of hiding it ?

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Got it ! Many thanks. But how can I change the colorbar name, and customize the ticks on it like I could do it for an axis in a graph (setup décimal or thousans separators per example).